# Simple nested sum giving ridiculous answer

Tags: symbolic, summation

I have produced a minimum working example of the issue I'm facing. I would like to evaluate the following symbol sum, with $n\geq0$:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{m=0}^{2(n-k)} x^m$$

If I evaluate this sum in Mathematica 12, and choose a particular value of $n$ (say, $n=2$) with a ReplaceAll (`/.`) command, I get a nonsensical result:

```
ClearAll[x,m,k,n];
N[
 Sum[
  Sum[
   x^m
  ,{m,0,2*(n-k)}]
 ,{k,0,n}]/.n->2 
]

-->(* (3. -1. x-3. x^2+x^7)/((-1.+x)^2 (1. +x)) *)
```

The result has powers of $x$ in the denominator, which is ridiculous since $m
\geq 0$ always. However, if I insert a particular value of $n$ beforehand, without a ReplaceAll, then I get the correct result.

```
ClearAll[x,m,k,n];
N[
 Sum[
  Sum[
   x^m
  ,{m,0,2*(2-k)}]
 ,{k,0,2}] 
]

-->(* 3. +2. x+2. x^2+x^3+x^4 *)
```

Why does this happen? How is Mathematica giving that weird result in the first case? I suspect the resolution to my puzzle may be quite simple.

Comment: `The result has powers of $x$ in the denominator, which is ridiculous since $m \geq 0$ always` But this is the known partial sum formula? Try `Sum[x^m, {m, 0, k}]` it gives the standard formula for partial sum `(-1 + x^(1 + k))/(-1 + x)`

Comment: See `Apart[Sum[x^m, {k, 0, n}, {m, 0, 2*(n - k)}] /. n -> 2]`.

Comment: `Sum[Sum[x^m, {m, 0, 2*(n - k)}], {k, 0, n}]` gives a general formula. When you insert a particular value of `n`, you do **exactly** that: merely _insert_ it. Simply do `FullSimplify` on the outcome, and you'll get the desired polynomial.

Answer (score 4):

The inner sum

```
Sum[x^m, {m, 0, 2*(n - k)}]
```

has the (well known and compact) representation:

[image]

Therefore the result is less weird as it seems